# Rails 7 Is it possible to remove data before migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I want to create migration where I delete some records and then change column type. Something like that:

```
  def up
    Company.where.not(activation_date: nil).delete_all
    change_column :companies, :activation_date, :datetime
  end

  def down
    Company.where.not(activation_date: nil).delete_all
    change_column :companies, :activation_date, :time
  end
```

But it looks like `change_column` execute before `.delete_all` because migration throws an error about converting `date` to `datetime`. Am I doing something wrong or it just can't be solved this way?

@Edit
Error:
`PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "activation_date" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone`

**Solution:**

```
  def up
    Company.where.not(activation_date: nil).delete_all
    change_column :companies, :activation_date, "timestamp USING ('2000-1-1'::date + activation_date)"
  end

  def down
    Company.where.not(activation_date: nil).delete_all
    change_column :companies, :activation_date, :time
  end
```

Comment: I think the delete is happening, my guess is that activerecord doesn't know how to convert the current saved dates to datetimes. Could you post the error to see if that's the case?

Comment: Yes, please edit the question to include your exact error, and the relevant parts of the `schema.rb` file.

Comment: May be this helps: `change_column :companies, :activation_date, 'datetime USING CAST(activation_date AS datetime)'`

Comment: @Dalemonaco @BenFenner but how is that possible if I remove every row with `activiation_date` by `Company.where.not(activation_date: nil).delete_all`? There shouldn't be data that needs to be converted. I tried even `Company.delete_all` and still the same

Comment: The reason you can't automatically case a Date to Timestamp is that they are completely different things. What should even be the correct result of that? `00:00`?`12:00`? What timezone should that be in? What PG is trying to tell you is that you need to actively choose how you want to cast it.

Comment: @mechnicov the type is timestamp/timestamptz on PG. Otherwise its correct.

Comment: @mechnicov I was trying it (changed `AS datetime` to `AS timestamp` because it didn't recognize type `datetime`) and I got error `cannot cast type time without time zone to timestamp without time zone`

Comment: Use `timestamptz`. The shorthand is `USING activation_date::timestamptz`

Comment: @max oh, ok, so even if I don't have any records in database I have to somehow define timezone in `change_column :companies, :activation_date, :datetime`, ye? But how ;v

Comment: Postgres timestamptz  doesn't actually store the timezone. It converts times to UTC. PG doesn't have a datatype which stores both a timestamp and the timezone as seperate "components". If you need to keep track of the timezone to fetch it back later you need two columns. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164203/how-to-get-the-timezone-from-a-postgresql-timestamp

Comment: I changed it to `change_column :companies, :activation_date, 'datetime USING activation_date::timestamptz' ` and still got error `PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type time without time zone to timestamp with time zone`

Comment: I did it! :D Thanks guys for the help and explanation! I used:
`change_column :companies, :activation_date, "timestamp USING ('2000-1-1'::date + activation_date)"`

Comment: Does rollback work correct?